How can I convert decimal to int using round function but with whole numbers in c#?
I want to convert for below sample values

Rounding to the 4th digit (first 3 digits should be 0). No decimals. E.g.: 89231.1 should be 89000, then  67898.125 will be 68000
Rounding to the 2th digit (first digit should be 0). No decimals. E.g.: 89.6 should be 90, then 87.36 will be 90
Rounding to the 1st digit. No decimals. E.g. 75.6 should be 76

I had tried Math.Round() function but it will not work for all cases.
For E.g:
var formula = (((50.2564 * 10*110)+5000);    
   var cal_value = Evaluate(formula);
   caluclated_value = Math.Round(cal_value, 0).ToString();

Where Evaluate logic is below:
static double Evaluate(string expression)
{
    try
    {
        var loDataTable = new DataTable();
        var loDataColumn = new DataColumn("Eval", typeof(double), expression);
        loDataTable.Columns.Add(loDataColumn);
        loDataTable.Rows.Add(0);
        return (double)(loDataTable.Rows[0]["Eval"]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

Now this value is rounding up but not with the whole number. The result is 60,282.04 withour rounding. After Rounding it will be 60,282. But I wan't 60,000 only.

You can divide the value (e.g. in the 1st case by 1000), then round to int, then multiply back.

Seems to be quite easily (without further improvements):
private static readonly int[] _factors = new[] { -1, 1, 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 10_000_000 };

public static int Round(double value, int position)
{
    var factor = _factors[position];
    var rounded = (int)Math.Round(value / factor, 0);

    return (int)(rounded * factor);
}

A running example can be found here.
